# Pattern for handling execution order of multiple callbacks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lua

---

I'm developing a role-playing game in C# (Unity) with a Lua scripting front-end for game logic and modding. I have a design question I've been thinking about and can't seem to find the answer. I'm implementing an Effect class, which provides a common interface to define and handle effects that affect champions or creatures, whether due to a spell, an enchanted item, or a condition (paralyzed, afraid...). The objective is to be as flexible as possible and decouple effects code from the actual champion components/classes.

I want the effect to have access to callbacks, so that it can alter what happens to the entity. If the character health changes for example, active effects can kick in and change that change before it's applied. Here are two examples in Lua, the API should be self-explanatory:

Ring of Health Loss Halving:

```
onHealthAdjustment = function(entity, val)
    if val < 0 then val = math.floor(val / 2); end
    return val;
end
```

Mana Shield spell:

```
onHealthAdjustment = function(entity, val)
    if val < 0 then
        championProperties = entity.championProperties;
        if championProperties then
            championProperties:adjustMana(val);
        end
        return 0;
    else
        return val;
    end
end
```

That's fine, but how to handle execution order of callbacks?

Let's say the champion loses 10 health. If the ring gets processed first, it lowers that to 5, then the spell reduces health loss to 0 and removes 5 mana instead.

If the spell gets processed first, it reduces health loss to 0, removes 10 mana, and then the ring callback gets a 0 and does nothing.

I can add an effect priority variable, but there would always end up some with the same value. Process in last-applied first order, or process last-applied only leads to stupid exploits with for example picking and clicking back items in the inventory to make sure what order the effects are processed... I don't see a way to call callbacks in parallel instead of sequentially...

I'm either not seeing an obvious way to fix the current pattern, or I need to change to another design pattern. I've read about Strategy and Observer patterns but can't seem to find a clear answer. How are these cases usually handled?

Thanks!

Comment: you may be interested in [promises](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1008068/Promises-for-Game-Development)

Comment: @MikeCorcoran I don't see how promises will help. This is not asynchronous code, and it doesn't *need* to be asynchronous code.

Comment: Yes, it doens't solve directly the problem, but an interesting read, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there would always end up some with the same value

So? If you get a collision, fix it. The order in which the effects are applied is not arbitrary, it's part of your design

Presumably in your code you have a list of event handlers per event type which you iterate through when the event happens. Just make sure that list is in the right order (e.g. by controlling the order they are registered) and you're done.

---

Side note. In case you didn't know, this:

```
 onHealthAdjustment = function(entity, val) end
```

Can be written like this:

```
 function onHealthAdjustment(entity, val) end
```

Comment: Well, as this aspect is open to modding, I cannot have final control over the design. The system must be flexible and be able to handle conflicts.

But how can I "fix it" if the event caller has no idea of what the callbacks contain as scripts?

Comment: PS: on the side note, yes I know, in this case these functions are defined as part as a table, hence the syntax:

`effect = {
    someVariable = 4,
    someOtherVariable = "hello",
    onUpdate = function() ... end,
    onHealthAdjustment = function() ... end,
}`

Comment: You control the *initial* design. The point is that health adjustment callbacks should be registered via some mechanism (e.g. 'addHealthAdjustmentCallback`) which manages order. FIFO makes as much sense as any other scheme, unless you want to allow users to insert at arbitrary locations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think I'll implement a way in which callbacks can be grouped in permutable classes where order doesn't matter, but decide by design the higher-level order of execution. For example all modifiers (+ or -) together first, then all multipliers (* or /) together, then all replacement effects last in FIFO. The callback object will provide the controller with info on what type of operation it intends to perform.